# Apache mod_rewrite: how to redirect addon domains subfolder access to addon domain itself?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, cpanel, add-on

Situation (directories tree) on an Apache server:

```
maindomain.com/
|
|_ .htaccess (just an empty file, no rule in here)
|
|_ addondomain1.com/
|  |
|  |_ .htaccess
|  |_ index.html
|
|_ addondomain2.com/
   |
   |_ .htaccess
   |_ index.html
```

Currently files in addondomain1.com can be viewed by going to:

```
http://www.addondomain1.com/index.html
http://www.addondomain1.com/
http://www.addondomain1.com
http://www.maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/index.html
```

**I would like to redirect all requests:**

`http://maindomain/addondomain1.com/some/path/anypage.html` (with or without 'www')

to same path/file but under addondomain1.com and always with 'www':

```
http://www.addondomain1.com/some/path/page.html
```

In order to try to accomplish this, I placed in `maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/.htaccess` this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.addondomain1\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://wwww.addondomain1.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

This one works almost great, and redirects well all the ones below:

```
http://addondomain1.com/index.html >> http://www.addondomain1.com/index.html
http://www.addondomain1.com/ >> http://www.addondomain1.com/
http://www.addondomain1.com  >> http://www.addondomain1.com
http://www.maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/index.html >> http://www.addondomain1.com/index.html
http://www.maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/ >> http://www.addondomain1.com/
http://maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/ >> http://www.addondomain1.com/
```

But unfortunately when going to:

```
http://maindomain.com/addondomain1.com
http://www.maindomain.com/addondomain1.com
```

**NOTE both links above are WITHOUT final slash**, it redirects to:

```
http://www.addondomain1.com//server/root/path/addondomain1.com
```

**I think the regexp `^(.*)$` is getting "addondomain1.com" as part because the final slash is missing. Do you know how fix/workaorund this issue?**

Thanks!

Comment: Hm...Do you want people to be able to go to `http://maindomain.com/addondomain1.com` in the first place?

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for looking at this questiom. Actually NO, I would like that when someone attempts to go to "http://maindomain.com/addondomain1.com/some/path/page.html" it gets ALWAYS redirected to "http://www.addondomain1.com/some/path/page.html". I UPDATED the question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: but that's all?! :) I'm gonna try this and let you know, thanks!

Comment: no, it does NOT wrok, I get exactly the same issue I was getting before. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: If not, can you enable your RewriteLog and give us a sample of what's happening? Also: why does this work: `http://www.main-domain.com/addon-domain-1.com/index.html >> http://www.addon-domain-1.com/index.html` as it wouldn't with your current setup: any other .htaccess rules we should know about?

Comment: I discovered the issue, the rewrite url in my question is correct, but I was adding 4 'w' chars in the RewriteRule and I also wrote them in the question. :( The RewriteLog showed it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.addondomain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://wwww.addondomain1.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```