# Apache .htaccess to redirect index.html to root, why FollowSymlinks and RewriteBase?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In order to redirect all `somefolder/index.html` (and also `somefolder/index.htm`) to `somefolder/` I use this simple rewrite rule in Apache .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

This works well!

But at [Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/only-validation/web/fix-canonical-issues-www-vs-non-www-and-more-on-apache-server?pli=1) they suggest to add also:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase /
```

1. **Could anyone be so kind to explain me why would i have to add these last lines, and explain me a bit what they mean and what they do?**
2. Is there a potential secuirty risk in not adding these lines?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Why they're suggested:

It's suggested that you add `Options +FollowSymlinks` because it's necessary that symlink following is enabled for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to work, and there's a chance that, while you may be allowed to turn it on, it's not enabled by the main server configuration. I suspect the reason that symlink following is necessary is beause the module makes a number of calls to `apr_stat()`, which looks like it needs to follow symlinks in order to get file information in all cases.

As for `RewriteBase`, it's typically not necessary. The documentation [goes on about it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but as most people's files *do* live under the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) somewhere, it usually only serves a purpose if you're redirecting externally and you use directory-relative URLs. To illustrate what I mean, consider the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^redirect index.html [R,L]
```

A request for *example.com/redirect* will result in an external redirect to *example.com/full/path/to/web/root/index.html*. The reason for this is that before it handles the redirection, mod_rewrite re-appends the current directory path (which is the default value of `RewriteBase`). If you modified `RewriteBase` to be `/`, then the path information would be replaced with that string, so a request for *index.html* would now be a request for */index.html*.

Note that you could just have done this explicitly on the replace too, regardless of the value of `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^redirect /index.html [R,L]
```

...works as intended, for example. However, if you had many rules that needed a common base and were being shifted around between directories, or your content wasn't under the root, it would be useful to appropriately set `RewriteBase` in that case.

#### The risk of not using them:

There's absolutely no security risk in not specifying `Options +FollowSymlinks`, because if you don't and it's not set by the main server configuration, mod_rewrite will always return 403 Forbidden. That's kind of problematic for people trying to view your content, but it definitely doesn't give them any extended opportunity to exploit your code.

Not setting `RewriteBase` could expose the path to your web content if you had an improperly configured rule set in one of your .htaccess files, but I'm not sure that there's any reason to consider that a security risk.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the time you took in explaining all this.  I wish I could upvote you more. I wonder if RewriteBase might be teh solution to solve this other question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242322/apache-mod-rewrite-how-to-redirect-addon-domains-subfolder-access-to-addon-domai

Comment: @Marco Demaio: No problem! As for your other question, I'll take a look at it later today and see if I have any suggestions.