# Why I do I get 403 Forbidden when viewing files affected by Apache RewriteRule if I have `Options -FollowSymLinks`?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symlink, http-status-code-403

I wanted to serve .xhtml files as

- `application/xhtml+xml` if the browser says that it accepts it.
- `text/html` otherwise

Then, I had this code:

```
<Files "*.xhtml">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !application/xhtml\+xml 
    RewriteRule .* - [T=text/html]
</Files>
```

And it worked well.

The problem is that, after disabling `FollowSymLinks` (I don't use symbolic links), instead of the .xhtml file I get 403 Forbidden error.

Why? Is `RewriteRule .* - [T=text/html]` a symbolic link?

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771175/apache-htaccess-to-redirect-index-html-to-root-why-followsymlinks-and-rewriteb

Comment: @Babblo I think that the questions ask different things, but part of the answer is common. But thanks for the link