# How can I escape slash sign `/` in Apache `<If>` directive's regex?

Tags: regex, apache, if-statement, escaping, slash

I wanted to serve .xhtml files as

- `application/xhtml+xml` if the browser says that it accepts it.
- `text/html` otherwise

I tried doing it with `mod_rewrite` but it didn't work with `Options -FollowSymLinks` (see [Why I do I get 403 Forbidden when viewing files affected by Apache RewriteRule if I have `Options -FollowSymLinks`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142285/why-i-do-i-get-403-forbidden-when-viewing-files-affected-by-apache-rewriterule-i)).

Then, I tried

```
<Files "*.xhtml">
    <If "%{HTTP:Accept} !~ /application\/xhtml\+xml/">
        ForceType text/html
    </If>
</Files>
```

But I get a syntax error: *Failed to compile regular expression*.

Meanwhile, I use this code...

```
<Files "*.xhtml">
    <If "%{HTTP:Accept} !~ /xhtml\+xml/">
        ForceType text/html
    </If>
</Files>
```

... which works, but I want to match the correct MIME type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an escape code like `\x2F` instead of the `/`.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like improving this is still under construction as of Apache 2.4. Apache team member "covener" [recommends](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#comment_3455) `m#regexp#` instead.

So your code would look like this...

```bsh
<If "%{HTTP:Accept} !~ m#application/xhtml\+xml#">
```

Comment: I can't see that comment_3455 by Covener. But the [Other](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#other) section says `m#regexp#` is an alternative of `/regexp/`.

Comment: Strange, the anchor shoots me directly to the correct discussion reply. But also great find on the official Other documentation table.

Comment: `m#regexp#` works well for me when evaluating against `REQUEST_URI`, which will have forward slashes in a typical scenario.

Comment: This answer is correct. But there are indeed no comments onthe linked page at all. And for sure not a comment by some Apache developer.

Comment: Yeah, comments section seems to be gone. Can't even find it archive.org snapshots. I'm fairly certain I didn't just invent `#comment_3455` anchor link at the time, Apache docs used to have a commenting section for sure.