# Consolidate duplicate URLs

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I'm getting the following critical error when running my website through Site Checker.

> Search engines see your `https://www.example.com` and
> `https://www.example.com/index.html` (or
> `https://www.example.com/index.php`) as different pages.
>
> If you don't explicitly tell Google which URL is canonical, Google
> will make the choice for you or might consider them both of equal
> weight, which might lead to unwanted behavior.

I can understand what it is telling me and I've spent many hours researching to find a fix but with no luck.  I've read Googles article (and watched the video) but this didn't give me any clues.  I'd already done the redirects due to another warning site checker previously gave me.

I've added the tag `rel="canonical"` unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file as suggested in another post.

```
# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.com/index.php
Redirect 301 /default.php https://www.example.com/index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache .htaccess to redirect index.html to root, why FollowSymlinks and RewriteBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771175/apache-htaccess-to-redirect-index-html-to-root-why-followsymlinks-and-rewriteb)

Comment: What is your canonical URL(s)? What URL are you using in your internal links? Your "redirects" would appear to suggest that having `/index.php` in the URL is canonical? But that isn't generally desirable. (?)

Comment: my internal links are all https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/whateverpage.php  and my  canonical URL is https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.php @MrWhite

Comment: @StephenOstermiller unfortunately not, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Your canonical URL should NEVER include `index.php` (or `index.html`).  The canonical URL should be just `https://mywebsite.co.uk/` for the home page.

Answer (score 1):

If your canonical URL is `example.com/index.php` (as opposed to simply `example.com/` - which is generally preferred<sup>***1**</sup>) then...

- Make sure you are linking to `/index.php` throughout your site (not simply `/`).
- Set the `rel="canonical"` tag to your canonical URL (ie. `https://www.example.com/index.php`). This should be enough to resolve the canonicalization issue that "Site Checker" is reporting, despite what it states.
- Create the following redirect at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root to redirect from `/` to `/index.php`.

  ```
  # Canonical redirect
  RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/index.php [R=301,L]
  ```

  (Test first with a 302 - temporary - redirect.)

> ```
> Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.com/index.php
> Redirect 301 /default.php https://www.example.com/index.php
> ```

Unless you previously had a `index.html` (or `default.php`) file that served your homepage content then these redirects are not required. (You should be using `RewriteRule` instead anyway - as above). Presumably requests for `index.html` or `default.php` return a "404 Not Found"?

---

#### <sup>***1**</sup> `example.com/` should be canonical, not `example.com/index.php`

Consider setting the canonical URL to `example.com/` instead of `example.com/index.php`. Using `example.com/` is generally expected, looks better, shorter. The `/index.php` part of the URL carries no SEO benefit. It is not necessary to include the `DirectoryIndex` in the URL-path.

For this, the process is the same as above, just the other way round. And the canonical redirect would be of the form:

```
# Canonical redirect from "/index.php" to "/"
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```